# Android Update Layout Content

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I'm looking for a way to update a layout's content with a new view. Is there any way to easily do this. It would be similar to how tabs work, but I don't want to have to get into extending the current tab structure if I don't have to.

The final result would be a few buttons that would switch the content in a specific linearlayout for each button.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at ViewSwitcher. This is designed to help with the kind of things you are suggesting.

If you want the contents in entirely different layout files, you can use a LayoutInflater and add the inflated view to the parent view.